# How do I match/search for a specific dictionary key?

Tags: c#

very new to c#.

I'm working with an API that returns a dictionary with 2 keys and 1 value.

This is my current code:

```
var dic = API.getVehicleValidMods((VehicleHash)sender.vehicle.model);
foreach (KeyValuePair<int, Dictionary<int, string>> kvp in dic)
{
    Dictionary<int, string> kvp2 = kvp.Value;
    foreach (KeyValuePair<int, string> kvp3 in kvp2)
    {
        API.consoleOutput("Key = {0}, Key = {1}, Value = {2}", kvp.Key, kvp3.Key, kvp3.Value);
```

Here is a sample from the result it returns:

[image: Sample from the console]

As you can see the first keys are sometimes the same number and they sometimes skip numbers.

I'm trying to return all matching "key number 2" that matches a certain "key 1".
The string values are not of importance in my case, I'm only interested in the ints.

So, my pseudo logic tells me something like
"foreach keynumber2 in keynumber1 (the integer, eg. 23) do this:" 
should work, however I'm unsure how to code it properly.

tl;dr How do i find all "key2" that matches a certain "key1" ?

Comment: What is "key 1" and "key 2" in your question?  Is "key 2" the key of an inner dictionary?  What do you mean by "matches?"  In your pic, none of the inner key values have the same key as any outer key value.  Are there some that will?  Or are you talking about the fact that key = 15, key = 0 is a match for key = 16, key = 0?

Comment: Key 1 is the first key(outer) on the sample screenshot, key 2(inner) is the second. 

By "matches", I meant that I want to find all "key 2" that matches a certain "key 1"  .

Hope that makes sense

Comment: So you're looking for instances where `kvp2[kvp.Key]` exists?

Comment: Please can you explain better the phrase "I want to find all "key 2" that matches a certain key 1 with an example taken from your screenshot (can you enlight your desired output)?

Comment: Yes, for an example on my screenshot there is 6 instances of  "key2" in "key1=16", i want to return them so I can use them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, you want to find all inner keys of specific outer key. You can do this with this line of code:

```
var key1 = 42;
var allKeys = dic.ContainsKey(key1)
  ? dic[key1].Keys.ToArray() 
  : new int[0];
```

If outer dictionary contains 42 as a key this will return all inner keys. Otherwise it will return an empty ints array.

Comment: Thank you very much, I feel embarrassed to even ask this, but "where" does it return? How do i view the results? a simple console output would be great

Comment: @nordmanden `allKeys` is an array of `int`. Use a `foreach` cycle on it. Like `foreach(var key in allKeys) Console.WriteLine(key);`

Comment: Thank you very much, we're getting close!
Now the only problem is that it returns the whole list every time, like so:
https://i.imgur.com/N4agnGi.png

How do I avoid that?

edit: My bad, scope issue. 

FIXED! Thank you very much, you're the man!

Comment: @nordmanden Please use one question for one specific problem. If you have additional question it would be better to ask a [New question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Answer (score 0):

```
var matchesFrom1 = from val in dic where val.Key == 1 select val.Value;
var valueList = from val in matchesFrom1 where val.Key == 2 select val.Value;
```

valueList is the string of values returned

Comment: Hi, thank you for the reply, really appreciate all the support i'm getting here. I went with solution 1, because it matches exactly what I was looking for. I really appreciate the reply nevertheless!

Answer (score 0):

You could use LINQ methods:

Use `.Where` method to filter your initial collection of `KeyValuePairs<>` by key.

Use `SelectMany` to flatten resulting `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<int, Dictionary<>>>` to a simple `IEnumerable<int>`

Use `Distinct` to make sure there are no duplicate keys (or omit this part if it is not necessary).

```
var someKey = 16;
var result = dic
            .Where(x => x.Key == someKey)
            .SelectMany(kv => kv.Value.Keys)
            .Distinct()
            .ToArray();
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply! I decided to go with "solution 1" because this was too complicated for me to understand.

Comment: By all means. This solution is much more complicated.